# What is the maximum characters the authentication and privacy keys can take for SNMPv3?

Tags: snmp, snmpd

For `authPriv` security level of SNMPv3 what is the maximum permissible length of authentication and privacy key we can give?
Please point me to some standard references.

Comment: I don't think there is a maximum length. Any time you use the key, you combine it with the engineID and hash it, so it will come out to a standard length, depending on the algorithm. I would recommend looking at RFC 3414